# Listen to gazebo topics using a python code

Tags: python

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please, is there a way to listen to gazebo topics from a python script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15651/listen-to-gazebo-topics-using-a-python-code/) by [elcymon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2963/elcymon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo doesn't officially support Python (as far as I know). There is [this other question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/924/how-to-use-python-with-gazebo/) asking how to use python with that answer.

The closest thing may be [this project](https://github.com/jpieper/pygazebo) which I don't know if it works.

---

Originally posted by [awesomebytes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/950/awesomebytes/) with karma: 28 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elcymon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2963/elcymon/) on 2017-11-29**:
I ended up using an independent listener written in c++